# Tabhost content not showing when i upgrade android.support.v4

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I am using `TabHost` and it was working fine till I updated the support library. When I updated the jar then tab content is not visible, only showing tab.

I am using `FragmentActivity`.

Here's the XML :

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@+id/tab_host"
    style="@style/FillParentWrapContent"
    android:layout_below="@id/view_location_card"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/view_margin" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        style="@style/FillParentWrapContent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_margin_extra_large" />
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Code snippet:

```
FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tab_host);
tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tab_content);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(CommonConstants.TAB_ID, tabTitleId);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Title").setIndicator(tabView), Fragment.class, bundle);
```

Please help me around this. I need to update the lib because I am using new feature like Marshmallow GPS permission.

I think this issue is due to because tabs are taking full width and so our `ListView` don't have space to show the content.

Comment: why you are not using **android.support.design.widget.TabLayout** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting a tabwidget like:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_margin_extra_large" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```